# Error output from the table

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pointers

Please run this code, and explain me why the output is like:

```
table[0]=3
table[1]=-858993567
table[2]=4
```

```
#include "stdafx.h"
struct First
{
    long data;
};

struct Second : public First
{
    char marker;
};

void printTable(First *table, int length)
{
    for (int i=0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        printf("table[%d]=%ld\n", i, table[i].data);
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Second myTable[3];
    myTable[0].marker='a';
    myTable[1].marker='b';
    myTable[2].marker='c';

    myTable[0].data=3;
    myTable[1].data=4;
    myTable[2].data=5;

    printTable(myTable, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function expects an array of `First` but you pass an array of `Second`. That just doesn't work.

You can use a pointer to base class to pass a *single* derived object, but not arrays. The indexing operator `[]` needs to know the exact type of the objects to be able to calculate where they are.

Comment: So for class arrays I cannot cast it to base class?<br>
Because when I would pass a single object of Second s;<br>
like printTable(&s, 1);<br>
then everything is alright;<br>

Comment: Right. You are actually passing a pointer to the first object of the array. To find the next object, the function needs to know the exact type (and thus the size) of each object. Otherwise it cannot find the second and third object of the array.